# Building Virtual Camera in OpenGL with Given Intrinsics

Tags: c++, opengl, projection-matrix

I am trying to get simulated depth image of an object model in OpenGL given the intrinsics parameters of a RealSense camera, `fx fy ppx ppy`.

I construct the projection matrix myself with the help from [this](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_projectionmatrix.html), [that](http://ksimek.github.io/2013/06/03/calibrated_cameras_in_opengl/) and also [that](http://kgeorge.github.io/2014/03/08/calculating-opengl-perspective-matrix-from-opencv-intrinsic-matrix). Somehow the result is not correct and I got confused with their conventions of intrinsics. They are using `alpha beta` which I believe are different from the focal length `f`.

My understanding of transforming from world coordinates to pixel coordinates is to use the intrinsics matrix. The projection from frustum to NDC also transforms between world and pixel coordinates. I don't understand how to combine them.

The second answer in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22064084/how-to-create-perspective-projection-matrix-given-focal-points-and-camera-princ) uses the exact coordinate system as mine but it does not work in my case as I still can't see any thing in my window. It will be great if someone can point to me on how to derive it from the basics.

This is my original working code to display.

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
gluPerspective(60, (float)(*width) / (*height), zNear, zFar);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
gluLookAt(camOrigin[0], camOrigin[1], camOrigin[2], camOrigin[0] + camLookAt[0], camOrigin[1] + camLookAt[1], camOrigin[2] + camLookAt[2], camUp[0], camUp[1], camUp[2]);
```

And I changed to this to make use of the intrinsics (I tried the transpose to see if it helps):

```
static const double fx = intrin.fx, fy = intrin.fy, cx = intrin.ppx, cy = intrin.ppy, zNear = 0.01, zFar = 20.0, s = 0;
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glPushMatrix();
GLdouble perspMatrix[16] = { 2 * fx / *width, 0, 0, 0,
        2 * s / *width, 2 * fy / *height, 0, 0,
        2 * (cx / *height) - 1, 2 * (cy / *height) - 1, (zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear), 1,
        0, 0, 2 * zFar*zNear / (zNear - zFar), 0};
//GLdouble perspMatrix[16] =
//{ 2 * fx / *width, 2 * s / *width, 2 * (cx / *height) - 1, 0,
//0, 2 * fy / *height, 2 * (cy / *height) - 1, 0,
//0, 0, (zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear), 2 * zFar*zNear / (zNear - zFar),
//0, 0, 1, 0 };
glMultMatrixd(perspMatrix);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glPushMatrix();
gluLookAt(camOrigin[0], camOrigin[1], camOrigin[2], camOrigin[0] + camLookAt[0], camOrigin[1] + camLookAt[1], camOrigin[2] + camLookAt[2], camUp[0], camUp[1], camUp[2]);
```

Any idea on what is wrong?

Comment: I applied the final equation in [this](http://kgeorge.github.io/2014/03/08/calculating-opengl-perspective-matrix-from-opencv-intrinsic-matrix) with `alpha = fx` and `beta = fy` and it kinda work but I am not sure why. They flip the sign of the third column because in their coordinates the camera is looking towards negative z-axis but mine is looking towards positive z-axis. Why does this still work in my case?

Comment: Hi, OpenGL cameras always look towards the negative z-axis, you cannot change that.

Comment: @ybungalobill hi, the sample code I have gotten is looking towards positive z-axis, with y-axis pointing down. I think you can change the viewing direction through gluLookAt()? I am using GLFW library if that makes a difference.